# MS Access - Make a subform display separate query results

Tags: ms-access, vba

First, note that I need to be rather 'general' about information in this post as it is work related.

Currently in MS Access I have a database which uses one large sheet for the data stored (lets say **tblDATASHEET**) along with other tables. Queries are used to select the specific columns related, using a **type_id**.

Users are searched from a listbox and the **type_id** is gathered.

For example, if **type_id** = TYP1, then run **qryTYP1**. 
**qryTYP1** might need columns 1, 2, 5, 6 and 11 from **tblDATASHEET**.
**qryTYP2** might only need columns 3, 4 and 5 from **tblDATASHEET**.

This all works fine. So when the user is searched and the appropriate query is run, a list of records for the user will appear. From here I would like to be able to create/edit records displayed.

Here's my problem, within query results for **tblDATASHEET**, when a new row is to be started/added, I would like certain fields to be auto-populated from the previous row. These fields are general fields such as name, title, dates, etc. Is this possible?

Let me know if I've been too brief and I can go in to further detail. I have spent a LOT of time mucking around with VBA and data macros, and have gotten close but not close enough.

Thank you,
Dre24.

**EDIT**
So I've decided to take the approach of displaying the query results within a subform on a form.

Now my issue is, how can I make a subform display alternate queries depending on input?

For example, the subform might need to display results from **qryTYP1** or **qryTYP2**, both two separate queries.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: When you say you're running qryTYP1 or qryTYP2, are then just opening a saved query object for the user to start adding data to? If so, perhaps consider opening these in forms or subforms instead... I answered a question with some guidance on how to do this recently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35912886/2140244 there's more events available to your to write VBA code on in forms/subforms.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help.

That's correct. I have considered using a form with a subform to display the results, but for example one query might have 6 columns displayed, and the next might have 40 columns displayed, and I couldn't figure out how to do this in a presentable way using forms/subforms and decided query results in general were the best way to handle this. However, is this the best way do you think (with forms and subforms)?

Thanks,
Dre.

Comment: I believe so. Forms/subforms have lots of events on them for you to write VBA code, which makes sense when you think that forms/subforms are *designed* for user interaction and therefore a developer would want a lot of options to control that user interaction. A query object, on the otherhand, isn't really meant to be used as a user interface and hence has very little (if any?) events for a developer to work with. A query object is more for creating views of your existing data rather than a way of collecting/editing new data via user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button like "Copy to New Record" on the form with search results. By click on this button capture ID of found row, scroll to/add/insert new empty record and copy required data from found record to new one.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Currently I am referring to just query results being displayed, so not in a form/subform. However I am now considering this approach and may use this, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to copy a record using a button click:

```
Private Sub btnCopy_Click()

  Dim rstSource   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld         As DAO.Field

  If Me.NewRecord = True Then Exit Sub

  Set rstInsert = Me.RecordsetClone
  Set rstSource = rstInsert.Clone
  With rstSource
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
      ' Go to the current record.
      .Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
      With rstInsert
        .AddNew
          For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
            With fld
              If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
              ElseIf .Name = "SomeFieldNotToCopy" Then
                ' Ignore this field.
              ElseIf .Name = "SomeSpecialField" Then
                ' Insert fixed or special value.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = SomeValue
              Else
                ' Copy field content.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
              End If
            End With
          Next
        .Update
        ' Go to the new record and sync form.
        .MoveLast
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
        .Close
      End With
    End If
    .Close
  End With

  Set rstInsert = Nothing
  Set rstSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav. I am now considering the form/subform approach to display data, so this will be very useful. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Would you say this is the best method, using forms/subforms? Currently I am just running queries and displaying them as query results in another tab.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that.